# Bitbucket - лицензия по умолчанию

Tags: лицензирование, авторские-права

Имеется свой проект и сторонняя либа на Bitbucket. В библиотеке отсутствует какая-либо информация о лицензии. Могу ли использовать эту библиотеку в своем коммерческом проекте, в частности запушить в свой репозиторий?

P.S. Гугл и справка по битбакету информации по этому поводу не дали.

Comment: Свяжитесь с разработчиком и узнайти у него.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Нет.

**Отсутствие лицензии есть запрет на всё.** Авторское право же.

Автор мог дать права **сервису хостинга репозиториев** на демонстрацию исходного кода просто фактом публикации, *но это должно быть указано в условиях использования сервиса*. **Вам** это никаких прав что-то делать с исходным кодом не даёт, если условия использования сервиса не утверждают чего-то иного.

Живой пример: тот факт, что я опубликовал здесь этот ответ, позволяет его использовать по лицензии [CC-BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) (с требованием атрибуции), поскольку по условиям использования StackExchange я публикую здесь контент именно под этой лицензией. Хотя я теоретически мог бы у себя в профиле указать, что мой контент можно использовать по [CC0](https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/), разрешив всем делать с моим контентом всё что угодно без каких-либо условий (в т. ч. атрибуции).

У Bitbucket та же история, только прав они требуют куда меньше и только для себя. Кто-то может явно приложить более разрешительную лицензию, но пока её нет, ничего делать нельзя.

Можете попробовать связаться с разработчиком и договориться о лицензировании под какой-нибудь мягкой лицензией, а можете договориться о явном разрешении на использование только для вас самих.

---

- См. также [**"Choose a license: no license"**](https://choosealicense.com/no-license/)